# Getting "TypeError: render is not a function" error when i import context from another file

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying to do react context on a function. Initially, I created react context in the same file as the provider, but then I got a warning on the console saying that I should put context in a separate file, but when I do that, for some bizarre reason, I get an error, even though I am pretty much doing the exact same thing, what am I doing wrong? I am only showing the relevant bits of the code.

The following code below works fine

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  NavLink,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './header.js';
import './OldApp.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//Context import commented
//import UserObjAndDbProvider from './dbAndUserObjContext';

import routes from './routes';

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

const Context = React.createContext();

export const UserObjAndDbProvider = Context.Provider;
export const UserObjAndDbConsumer = Context.Consumer;


const App = ({ user, database }) => {

  var [membership, setMembership] = useState(false);

  const docRef = database.collection("userCollection").doc(`${user.uid}`)

   //get data 
   const FindOutMembership = async () => {
      var booleanVal = null;
      docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          const booleanVal = doc.data().membership;
          setMembership(membership = booleanVal);
        } else {
          console.log("Error: no such document exists")
        }
      })
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      FindOutMembership();
   })
 
  return (
    <UserObjAndDbProvider value={'i am sexy and i like it'}>
      <Router>
         //some routing stuff done here
      </Router>
      </UserObjAndDbProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

but when i take context stuff out, and put in in another file(which is in the same folder) and import it i get a weird error titled "TypeError: render is not a function"

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  NavLink,
  Switch,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './header.js';
import './OldApp.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

//Context import now uncomment
import UserObjAndDbProvider from './dbAndUserObjContext';

import routes from './routes';

import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

import { useContext, createContext } from 'react';

const App = ({ user, database }) => {

  var [membership, setMembership] = useState(false);

  const docRef = database.collection("userCollection").doc(`${user.uid}`)

   const FindOutMembership = async () => {
      var booleanVal = null;
      docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          const booleanVal = doc.data().membership;
          setMembership(membership = booleanVal);
        } else {
          console.log("Error: no such document exists")
        }
      })
   }

   useEffect(() => {
      FindOutMembership();
   })

   //console.log(membership);

  return (
    <UserObjAndDbProvider value={'i am sexy and i like it'}>
      <Router>
         //some routing stuff done here
      </Router>
      </UserObjAndDbProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

my context file is called dbAndUserObjContext.js and looks like this

```
import React from 'react'

import { createContext } from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext();

export const UserObjAndDbProvider = Context.Provider;
export const UserObjAndDbConsumer = Context.Consumer;

export default Context;
```

Comment: You're importing the default export. Did you mean to import {UserObjAndDbProvider} ?

Comment: But i am importing that arent i? im a bit confused about what you mean

Comment: I'm not sure if you've mixed up default and named exports, but it seems you are default importing `UserObjAndDbProvider` which is the context, so if you are wrapping the app you need to wrap it with the provider, i.e. `<UserObjAndDbProvider.Provider value={....}>...`.

Comment: Holy cow! that fixed the problem! i dont understand what you said, could you please explain it to me again? what is the the difference between default import and named export, i tried googling it and i am still a little bit confused

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out, i cant believe i made such a dumb mistake.